# Do indexes maintain query performance when additional data is added?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Was asked today how our read queries might be affected by an increase of ~1,000,000 rows.  The queries are heavily indexed and are very fast ~1ms.  Is it true that because we have indexes that the query performance should remain relatively the same regardless of how much new data we add?  Is it just that the index size on disk will continue to grow? Can someone explain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too generic; it is hard to answer without seeing the actual queries and table structure.

There are queries that can result in full table scan despite the table being indexed (ex. queries containing LIKE condition). There are also queries which will generally use the index. Also, depending on the statistics gathered by your DBMS, it may decide that using the index is more inefficient than simply doing a full table scan, in result ignoring your index.

So in short, indexes can tremendously improve the performance of some queries, while other queries may find them inefficient and ignore them. If your queries are of the second type than increasing the amount of data in the table will definitely increase query execution time.